# Typescript enum as key in specified object expected an error but had no

Tags: typescript, object, enums

I have got some strange behavior of TS while work with enums as object keys.
I expect TS error, but it is not, and I don't understand why.

```
enum List {
  sm = "sm",
  md = "md",
}

export interface Dictionary<T = any> {
  [index: string]: T;
}
export type OptionalDictionary<T, K extends string = string> = { [P in K]?: T };

type MessageType = Dictionary<string | null>;
type MessagesType = OptionalDictionary<MessageType, List>;
type Values = { receiver: List; text: string };

const values = { receiver: List.sm, text: "123" };
const { receiver, text } = values;

const data: MessagesType = {
    // [receiver]: { text }, // correct
    [receiver]: text // wrong, but no error
};

const data2: MessagesType = {};
// data2[receiver] = { text }; // correct
data2[receiver] = text; // wrong, had error

console.log(data[receiver] === data2[receiver]); // true
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAMglgZwC5QN4CgpQdAvFAIhwIBpMoIATKfAq09AX3XWAA8AHAewCcU4QSYDwBmAQwDGwKABE4EpHC4gxPAJ4AeACo0oYkGoB8acgG0BldgC5sSHgIDmAXRtaA3E1adeKJGo7SAPIcispiADZyCkoq6tokUADSUOxCIJQItvYgDrrI2Q7G%20KhQpgAKUAJJTgD8rlCMHuh%20AVAAssAICGIOwFr%200vhRobGa%20Y5QAD5Q4OHhhh4t0h1dPZ39rfjBIxHDMaqaK929G8AJ8MgLzQNQAGoRYJ26JTzAUnAAbsI2F0huUEI2EgbOMcg0mhJlMgoB8Hk9ilBXu8vjwfogkAA6HAJQHAwgARgATABmAjg9CQkDQl5vYCfYQ41INXSw8KPBAQqEoShiJBiGxHNYIU7PchYAD04tKSLpKJcaABTMYCUlUEhPCRSDF0tp9J48txUFVAHceMoHAkAEZgFAgLgpDW8Jicqnc3liQkCzrHdY3YqNdCqnl8wmmGV6pzPRVA8FGqXqzXoYMesO6uW6XH-E1mnIJAAWYmowjNPBYlIQXHCwAx4S4DgAFMnU8jhJHcO2oMnQ%20G5QBKLNSuyPdBAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the interaction of a few unfortunate behaviors in TypeScript.

First, computed keys of union types are widened all the way to a `string` index, as is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), a longstanding bug/limitation.  So the type of `{[receiver]: text}` is seen as `{[k: string]: string}` instead of something like `{sm: string} | {md: string}`.  I'm not sure when or if that will be changed, but that's what's happening.

Second, index signatures (like `{[k: string]: string}` are always considered assignable to weak types (types with all optional properties, like `{sm?: {text: string}, md?: {text: string}}`), even if the index signature's property type is incompatible with the weak type's property types!  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#27144](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27144), also considered a bug.  Again, no idea when or if this will be addressed; it's listed as "future".

Both of those bugs put together give you the behavior you see: you're allowed to assign `{[receiver]: text}` to a variable of type `MessagesType` with no error.  That's the explanation; not sure what you should do except possibly go to those two GitHub and give them a ?

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this deep answer, now I have understanding of this case.
As solution I decide to use `data` as array instead of object, have some problems with concatenation feather, but TS works correctly